# Copy the last 'n' lines of a file to another file in reverse order

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, operating-system, system-calls

I am working on system calls in Ubuntu and implementing it using C language. I wrote this code to do the aforesaid but in the destination file say, "b.txt", I am only getting 'n' number of blank lines instead of the desired texts in those lines.
I can't figure out if there is some logical error here or do I need to change the permission conditions/values (mode) for open() corresponding to fd2?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int n, fd1, fd2, choice=0;
    
    char sPathName[100], dPathName[100], c;
    
    printf("Enter name of the source file: \n");
    scanf("%s", sPathName);
    
    while(access(sPathName, F_OK) != 0) //Given file doesn't exist (in the this directory)
    {
        printf("The file \"%s\" does not exist in the given directory!", sPathName);
        printf("\n\nEnter name of a valid source file: \n");
        scanf("%s", sPathName);
    }
    
    fd1 = open(sPathName, O_RDONLY);
    
    printf("\nEnter the integer value of number of lines, 'n': \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("\nEnter name of the destination file: \n");
    scanf("%s", dPathName);
    
    if(access(dPathName, F_OK) != 0)    //Given file doesn't exist (in this directory)
    {
        fd2 = open(dPathName, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY, 0666);
    }
    
    else
    {
        printf("\nA file by the name \"%s\" already exists in this directory! \nDo you want to: \n1) Overwrite it \n2) Append to it? \nChoice: ", dPathName);
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            fd2 = open(dPathName, O_WRONLY);
        }
        
        else if(choice == 2)
        {
            fd2 = open(dPathName, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND);
        }
        
        else
        {
            printf("\nInvalid choice! Exiting program...\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    while(n != 0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            lseek(fd1, -1, SEEK_END);
            
            read(fd1, &c, 1);
            write(fd2, &c, 1);
            
            if(c == '\n')
            {
                break;
            }
        }
                
        n--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some example input you use, the resulting actual output and the expected output. Generally you should check the return value of all non-void functions. Functions might indicate an error or a specific situation by returning -1, NULL, 0 or a number less than expected. `read` and `write` might read or write less than requested.

Comment: @userUser – Yes, there is some logical error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the following loop:

```
while(n != 0)
{
    while(1)
    {
        lseek(fd1, -1, SEEK_END);
            
        read(fd1, &c, 1);
        write(fd2, &c, 1);
            
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
                
    n--;
}
```

Before reading every character, you seek to the last character of the file. This means that you are always only reading and writing the last character of the file. If this character is a newline character, then you will write lots of blank lines.

In order for your approach to work, you should first read and write the last character, then the second-to-last character, then the third-to-last character, etc., until you have found the required number of newline characters.

In order to find the newline character of the last line in the file that should not be written, you should first seek to the last character of the file using

```
lseek(fd1, -1, SEEK_END);
```

which you are already doing, but after reading that character, you should not use that function call again, but should instead use

```
lseek(fd1, -2, SEEK_CUR);
```

to jump back one character and to also jump over the character that you just read (so 2 characters in total). Afterwards, you should always use

```
lseek(fd1, -2, SEEK_CUR);
```

instead of

```
lseek(fd1, -1, SEEK_END);
```

after reading every character, until you find the newline character of the last line in the file that should not be written.

Also, it is generally advisable to check the return values of the system calls. Otherwise, your program will likely misbehave if, for example, the entire text file consists of less than `n` lines.

Therefore, I recommend that you change your code to the following:

```
//attempt to seek to the last character of the file
if ( lseek(fd1, -1, SEEK_END) == -1 )
{
    perror( "lseek" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

while ( 1 )
{
    ssize_t ret;

    //attempt to read a character
    ret = read(fd1, &c, 1);
    if ( ret != 1 )
    {
        if ( ret == -1 )
        {
            perror( "read" );
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Encountered unexpected return value from \"read\"!\n" );
        }
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //attempt to write a character
    ret = write( fd2, &c, 1 );
    if ( ret != 1 )
    {
        if ( ret == -1 )
        {
            perror( "write" );
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Encountered unexpected return value from \"write\"!\n" );
        }
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //count the number of newline characters and break out
    //of infinite loop if we have reached the limit
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        if ( n-- == 0 )
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    //jump back two characters in the file
    if ( lseek(fd1, -2, SEEK_CUR) == -1 )
    {
        perror( "lseek" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

Note that this code additionally requires `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of the file.

For the input

```
This is line1.
This is line2.
This is line3.
This is line4.
This is line5.
This is line6.
This is line7.
This is line8.
```

and with `n` equal `5`, this code has the following output:

```
.8enil si sihT
.7enil si sihT
.6enil si sihT
.5enil si sihT
.4enil si sihT
```

Note that all characters are written in reverse order, including the newline characters. As a consequence, the first line is empty, because the first character written is a newline character.

It is also worth noting that performing three system calls for every character is highly inefficient. A more efficient approach would read several kilobytes at once.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! 
In the lseek statement within the infinite while loop, why do we move the pointer by 2 places back (valued -2 as shown in your code), rather than just 1 place back (-1) for each iteration?

Comment: @userUser: Every time you read one character, you advance the file position by one. So if you want to read characters backwards, you must read one character, then jump back by two characters, then read one character, then jump back by two characters, etc. If you only jump back by one character, you would always be reading the same character again.